# how to send the reqursted MAC address as a argument while redirect to a URL using Iptables?

Tags: iptables, ebtables

I want to redirect the clients to different URL. I have done this using port redirection. But Now I want the MAC address of the client as a argument for the URL. How can I get the MAC address and send with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address , is not something you can get from the Applicaton level, eg: the client browser or the server.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model for how far apart it is.
It is like asking for maintenance of the ignition plug from the dashboard of a passenger seat.

If, and only if, your client side will allow running custom made binary executables, that lookup for the MAC address of the network interface, and somehow phone-home to your server, is this possible. If you are looking for MAC address besed block/accept for a WiFi router, notice that they only work on the local interface level, meaning, just near the router.
MAC address is used, TO transport IP packets on the hardware level, however, as soon as it reaches another router, it is dicarded. Only the IP packet will survive the long journey of travelling through multiple routers, modifying the TTL along the way untill it reaches your server.

A better approach would be to handle client side detection with
Cookie + https + 1x1 dot images to track unique visitors, and user agents, all combined
with a login/password pair.
Detecting if it is a valid client, based on the cookie is much practical then 
trying to install a binary on client's side to peek for a MAC address that may not
even be unique (if they modify it with tools, it can be anyting...)